# Почему не работает PayPal на сервере?

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

PayPal работает на localhost нормально, а на сервере нет. Тестовые деньги снимает, но не идет редирект после оплаты. Что это может быть ?

Comment: Нерабочий скрипт... Мы там рядом с вами чтоль сидим? Может быть все что угодно, раз на локалке работает, а на сервере нет, то значит проблема в среде, копайте в эту сторону

Answer (score 2):

Причин может быть море. Пару подсказок:

1. Если обрабатываете запросы через cURL, убедитесь что указан User Agent. И какой-то реальный.
2. Для возврата на сайт можете указывать в форме запроса result url (backurl)вот так:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://mysite.com/paypal/result/">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://mysite.com/paypal/success/">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="https://mysite.com/paypal/fail/">
```

После успешной оплаты вернется на **return**, после неуспешной на **cancel_return**.